# Array of Classes

Tags: c#, arrays, class, methods, random

I'm having a problem with my program a little bit.

I created a class like this in my programs:

```
class ClassA
{
    public int number = -1;

    public Random rnd = new Random();
    public void randomize()
    {
         var random = rnd;
         number = rnd.next(4)+2;
    }

}
```

I was going to create and array which each of the array contain a class,
which i created like this. I transferring the array to a new method so I can check on it.

```
public static void Main()
{
    ClassA[,] arrayOfClass = new Class[6,6];
    ClassA classA= new Class();
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
         for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
         {

              classA.randomize();

              arrayOfClass[i, j] = classA;
         }
    }
    CheckClassA(arrayOfClass);
}
private void CheckClassA(ClassA[,] arrayOfClass)
{
     int i,j;
     for(i=0;i<6;i++)
     {
         for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
         {
         Console.Writeline("Randoming : "+arrayOfClass[i,j].number);
         {
     }
}
```

When I run these, the console only produce the same number over and over, but different on every run, its like it only randomize it once then never randomize it again.

My Question are:
1. Why my program only randomize once and return the same number on all the value of the array?
2. Does my method of transferring array wrong?

I tried using other type below to check if my randomize failed, but no it didn't because its returning the random number as I expected.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        ClassA[,] arrayOfClass = new Class[6,6];
        ClassA class= new Class();
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
             for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
             {

                  class.randomize();

                  arrayOfClass[i, j] = class;
                  Console.Writeline("Randoming : " + arrayOfClass[i,j].number);
             }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion and help are appriciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is being caused because of the fact that you're not actually creating new `ClassA` objects,  you're just using the same one to each array index. You also seemed to misspell `ClassA` in some places as `Class`, I'm not sure how it compiled like it was. Move your Class initialisation into the loop where you're assigning to `arrayOfClass`.

```
public static void Main()
{
    ClassA[,] arrayOfClass = new ClassA[6,6];
    //ClassA classA= new Class();
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            classA = new ClassA();
            classA.randomize();
            arrayOfClass[i, j] = classA;
        }
    }
    CheckClassA(arrayOfClass);
}
```

When this is done you will run into another issue of them all returning the same number for a very different reason.

---

It produces the same number because each ClassA is created within a very close time period and [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) is initialised with the same seed.

This is from the [Random()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx) default constructor page on MSDN:

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by using a single Random object to generate all random numbers. You can also work around it by modifying the seed value returned by the system clock and then explicitly providing this new seed value to the Random(Int32) constructor. For more information, see the Random(Int32) constructor.

So basically because `Random` is pseudo random it's initialised by a number that is based on the system clock. Your best way around this is to share the same `Random` object between  all instances of `ClassA`, either by making it `static` or passing an instance of `Random` in to the `randomize` method.

This should fix the problem (making it `static`):

```
class ClassA
{
    public int number = -1;

    public static Random rnd = new Random();
    public void randomize()
    {
         var random = rnd;
         number = rnd.next(4)+2;
    }

}
```

Comment: Also `var random = rnd;` does nothing and can be removed.

Comment: @Austin so i can delete it? Thanks for the suggestion.

Daniel, This answer help me a lot. and giving me an understanding of what my mistakes is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make random object static, so every instance of class refers to it.

This is because C# uses pseudo random algorithm, where every next value is somehow depended on previous value.

For parameterless instantiation of Random class it uses current clock value by default, so every instance of your class creates Random object with the same starting value and calling Next() to them returns the same value, than this value is used for another Next() and those values are same too.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue you're having is that your array is always set to the same object, for each entry. You need to `new` up a new ClassA every time you iterate through, otherwise you're only going to be pointing to the last .number.

Of course, this is in addition to the little 'would be using a new Random() every time', which you should make static like so:

```
public static void Main()
{
        ClassA[,] arrayOfClass = new ClassA[6,6];
        ClassA classA;
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
                for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    classA = new ClassA(); // MISSING THIS LINE CAUSED ARRAY TO ONLY HAVE LAST ENTRY
                    classA.randomize();

                    arrayOfClass[i, j] = classA;
                }
        }
        CheckClassA(arrayOfClass);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void CheckClassA(ClassA[,] arrayOfClass)
    {
            int i,j;
            for(i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Randoming : " + arrayOfClass[i, j].number);
                }
            }
    }

     public class ClassA
     {
         public int number = -1;

         public static Random rnd = new Random();
         public void randomize()
         {
             number = rnd.Next(4) + 2;
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: Oh, yeah! Thanks Rob, I missed this one.